# Why baseURL in nuxt builded app always like baseURL for server app?

Tags: nuxt.js

I need the generated nuxt application send requests to '/'. Thus, the api of the application will be in the same place where its static generated files are located.

I faced with problem: when running 'nuxt generate' process.server is true and process.browser is false. During generating, nuxt send queries to server *baseURL* (localhost:3000), it's ok. But generated javascript code also trying send queries to localhost:3000.

I run command

```
 http-server -c-1 -p 3001 ./dist/
```

and open localhost:3001 in browser, I see generated page, and error in console:

```
 Failed to load http://localhost:3000/data/pages.db
```

In my nuxt.config.js

```
  axios: {
    browserBaseURL: '/',
  },
```

When I run *npm run dev* in browser all right, browser send requests to '/', but generated app still send requests to localhost:3000

How I can resolve this issue?

**UPD:** 
I need get *json* files from */static* in *asyncData*. I think, I found solution.

I use *axios*, not *@nuxtjs/axios* and do following in one place:

```
 axios.defaults.baseURL = typeof window === 'undefined' 
     ? 'http://localhost:3000' : window.location.origin
```

and after that in any component

```
 import axios from 'axios'
```

in *asyncData*:

```
 axios.get(`/data/teasers/${path}`)
```

In result, I can generate static files, place it to any domain, and js code can corrrectly get files from */static*

I hope this will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

A late response, that might be useful for other people.

If you wish to keep the code of your Nuxt application simple, you can use the `@nuxtjs/axios` module, and use a plugin to specify the *baseUrl* used from the browser.

```sh
yarn install '@nuxtjs/axios'
```

In nuxt.config.js:

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/axios-set-client-baseurl.js'
  ],
```

In plugins/axios-set-client-baseurl.js:

```js
export default function ({ $axios }) {
  if (process.client) {
    $axios.setBaseURL(window.location.origin)
  }
}
```